# what can i do to make my code to work

Tags: c#, checkbox, combobox, streamwriter

i have 4 errors and im working on my save button if i could get these fixed it will only save the selected items that the user wants

THIS IS NOT all the code just the code that im having problems with. this program is for and icecream application with 2 combo boxes and 3 check boxes

I PUTT COMMENT LINES WHERE I HAVE THE ERRORS ARE AT

```
  private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(
                                            new FileStream(sfd.FileName,
                                                            FileMode.Create,
                                                            FileAccess.Write)
                                                            );
            if(flavorBox) // i have an error right here (Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' to 'boolean)

            {
                sw.WriteLine(flavorBox.SelectedItem);

            }
            else(syrupBox) //syays i need semecolons right here for some reason
            {
                sw.WriteLine(syrupBox.SelectedItem);


            }
            if (Nuts.Checked)
            {
                this.Tag = "checked";
                sw.WriteLine(Nuts);

            }
            else(Cherries.Checked) //says i need semicolons here to i dont know why
            {
                this.Tag = "checked";
                sw.WriteLine(Cherries);

            }
            if(Sprinkles.Checked)
            {
                this.Tag = "checked";
                sw.WriteLine(Sprinkles);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }


    }
```

THIS IS MY 4TH ERROR

```
       private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to send the data back?",
             "Data Sender",
             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
             MessageBoxIcon.Warning);



        if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel() = true;  //ITS ASKED ME AM I MISSING A DIRECTIVE OR ASSEMBLY REFRENCE (FOR CANCEL)
        }
```

Comment: what `if(flavorBox)` should mean?

Comment: that is the name of my combox

Comment: comboboxes does not have names, it could be the name of your variable, anyway - what do you want to check with this condition?

Comment: What are you actually checking in your if statement?  If something is aside from the default is selected?

Comment: im checking in my if statements that the user slects a flavor out of the flavor box and the syrup box etc then save what the user selected and be able to open the saved file and see what the seleced

Comment: you're probably looking for `if (flavorBox.SelectedIndex != 0)`.  This is assuming the first/default value is "select a flavor" or something similar

Answer (score 2):

In an if-else only the if should have a condition, and the else should not. Use an else if statement to explicitly define a condition.

```
if (Nuts.Checked)
{
        this.Tag = "checked";
        sw.WriteLine(Nuts);
}
else if(Cherries.Checked)
{
    this.Tag = "checked";
    sw.WriteLine(Cherries);

}
else if(Sprinkles.Checked)
{
    this.Tag = "checked";
    sw.WriteLine(Sprinkles);
}
```

Flavorbox is a textbox, so by doing if(flavorbox) you are checking if flavorbox is equal to true or false. It's a textbox so this isn't possible. You'll probably have to just change the flavorbox. Try the following:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(flavorbox.Text)) {
    sw.WriteLine(flavorBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: flavor box and syrupbox are combo boxes

Comment: See if this works `if(flavorBox.SelectedItem != null)` to check if a value has been selected.

Comment: yes it worked and got rid of my syntax errors.=). but i cant run the program till i get rid of the other 2 errors  =(

Comment: it still writes everything int he combo boxes and doesnt even touch the check boxes when i view the saved file in note pad

Answer (score 0):

**1.** about

```
if(flavorBox)
```

what are you checking?

about the:

`else(syrupBox)` and `else(Cherries.Checked)`

you cannot do `else(something)`.
you can do `else if(something)`
because `else` is all the rest of the options.
so change them to:
`else if(syrupBox)` and `else if(Cherries.Checked)`

**2.** about the cancel:
what are you trying to do?

when you click no in the dialog, what are you trying to accomplish with the `e.cancel`?

Comment: cancel is still undelined says does not contain defintion are you missing a directive or assembly refrence

Comment: i get the error no overload for  FormClosingEventArgs e) match delegate event handler

Answer (score 0):

For the fourth error, note that `EventArgs.Cancel` is a property, not a method. Remove the brackets:

```
e.Cancel = true;
```